# Unit test case - Pass and fetch a value from a query string parameter

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am using .NET Core. I want to pass value from query string parameter from unit test function to the azure function. I am facing issue with passing and accessing the  query string parameter value.

The URL is `https://localhost:4300/api/RolePageMapping?EnterpriseId=xyz`

I want to use the query string parameter inside Azure function. The code is as below.

```
 public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
                                             
                string EnterpriseId = req.Query["EnterpriseId"];
        }
```

I want to know how can I pass the value from my unit test function to Azure function?

```
[Fact]
public async Task Function_ReturnBadRequest()
{
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequest>();

    var logger = new MockLogger();

    var actualResult = await
    GetUserRolePageMapping.Run(request.Object, logger);
    actualResult.Should().BeOfType<HttpResponseMessage>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to mock the [`HttpRequest.Query Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.httprequest.query?view=aspnetcore-2.2#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Http_HttpRequest_Query) of the `HttpRequest`

```
[Fact]
public async Task Function_ReturnBadRequest() {
    //Arrange
    var expectedValue = new StringValues("Hello World"); //Or what you want
    var request = new Mock<HttpRequest>();
    request
        .Setup(_ => _.Query["EnterpriseId"])
        .Returns(expectedValue);

    var logger = new MockLogger();

    //Act
    var actualResult = await GetUserRolePageMapping.Run(request.Object, logger);

    //Assert
    actualResult.Should().BeOfType<HttpResponseMessage>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To build more complex query strings we can use QueryCollection class. It’s a little bit unconveniet beast but it has everything we need to build up query strings from values we have.

Building query string using QueryCollection class needs three steps:

- Create instance of StringValues class. It’s a class that takes either
  string or array of strings to its constructor. This class holds
  values for query string parameter.
- Create    Dictionary<string,StringValues> for query parameters. Add
  query    parameter name and instance of StringValues to dictionary.
  Repeat it    for all query parameters.
- Create instance of
  QueryCollection and use    dictionary as contructor argument.

  ```
  [Fact]   
    public async Task ViewPdf_returns_view_if_document_exists_and_html_was_asked()
  ```

  {

  ```
   var model = new ApplicationReviewModel();
   var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, StringValues>();
   dictionary.Add("showhtml", new StringValues("1"));
   dictionary.Add("showtoc", new StringValues("0"));

   _controller.Request.Query = new QueryCollection(dictionary);

   _applicationServiceMock.Setup(a => a.GetDocumentReview(It.IsAny<Guid>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
                          .ReturnsAsync(() => model);

   var result = await _controller.ViewPdf(Guid.NewGuid()) as ViewResult;

   Assert.Same(model, result.Model);
   Assert.Equal("ApplicationPdf", result.ViewName);
  ```

  }